# Javascript how to make a reset button

Tags: javascript, html

Once a user enters lets say 5 numbers into that list I want to have a reset button so if the user wants to delete them all instantly they can click reset which should delete the entire list....

I have tried making a reset button with a reset function that fetches the element by id and tries to delete it but it did not quite work so I am hoping someone here knows how to do that...

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/bikbouche1/QVUHU/67/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/JTXN7/1/). Key code:

```
document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = "";
};
```

To clarify, since this appears to have confused other posters - the "numbers" `div` is a placeholder for one or more dynamically-created `input` elements, *not* a reference to the original "number" `input`. By setting `innerHTML` to `""`, the above code deletes the dynamically created elements entirely - it's not trying to clear their values.

Comment: I just looked at your updated fiddle and it doesn't appear to work

Comment: that works, Cory's code is buggy but rabino works, Ryan I know the updated version isnt working becasue I cant seem to figure out why my index array button isnt working: http://jsfiddle.net/bikbouche1/QVUHU/82/

Comment: @Ryan - This is working for me in Chrome and FF - didn't test in IE. I didn't change/fix the OP's code at all - I just added the "Reset" button and the handler. So if there were errors in the original implementation I didn't try to fix them.

Comment: @nrabinowitz I just tested the reset button and used Chrome for this test, I just tried in FF and Chrome again and still didn't work. I don't have IE due to using Ubuntu, Weird. @ErrorErrorError personally I would use firebug to debug the array

Comment: @Ryan - Note that this *isn't* supposed to clear the existing input field (you're correct, my reset button doesn't do that). It's supposed to clear the *new* input fields that are created after you click "Add". I believe that's what the OP was going for.

Comment: ah... sorry about the misunderstanding, I think the labeling of the button could be more specific for a better user experience. I will trust that it is working in this case

Comment: @Ryan - Totally agree about the button label. Also the button probably shouldn't even show up until new numbers have been added. But I figured those issues were out of scope :).

Comment: You're right there, it is out of scope, we're only here to help not to re-write! hehe

Comment: Ah, SO. So nice that 4 years later people still care enough to come back, misunderstand the question, and downvote. :)

Comment: @nrabinowitz: just spotted your comment by chance. The DV was mine, though I've changed my mind and reversed it. Apologies, I should have explained it: I read the conversation between you and Cory W, and felt you were rather too hard on him.

Comment: @halfer - You may be right; he certainly seemed to think so, and I could have been more civil. But I don't think he ever understood the OP's actual use case, which admittedly was a bit unclear.

Comment: Thanks @nrabinowitz, and fair enough. It's a hard balance to strike, admittedly - I find myself often reading my old comments and thinking I could have turned up the diplomacy a notch, especially when I am interacting with new users. My approach is, err, a "work in progress"!

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that you could always just use a simple

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

if you want to clear the entire form. Note that you'll need to move those inputs that are currently outside of the form tags in your fiddle to within the form tags for this to work.

Here's an updated [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QVUHU/81/)

Also note that nrabinowitz's answer won't work for two reasons. First of all, the incorrect ID was given ("numbers" instead of "number") and also, .innerHTML will *not* work for an input field. Instead you should use:

```
document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("number").value = "";
};
```

An updated, working version of his fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JTXN7/2/).

Comment: This code is not "buggy." It is the standard HTML reset input type! http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.reset.html - Yeesh!

Comment: Reset is definitely the way to go. Just note that it doesn't "clear" forms, rather, it resets form controls to their (un)specified default values.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for the clarification, Matt.

Comment: @Matt and @Cory - did you look at the OP's implementation? It isn't just a question of clearing the input fields (in which case I'd completely agree about the standard reset) - it's a question of creating and deleting new `input`s on the fly.

Comment: @Cory - I'm sorry, but both of the places you think my code is mistaken are incorrect. The "numbers" div is the placeholder for new `input` elements; the reference to it is correct; and the `innerHTML` line is deleting the *elements*, not clearing their value. Please pay attention before criticizing other folks' answers.

Comment: My mistake. OP's way of doing this is... unique, so I misunderstood. Regardless, your fiddle does not work as posted on my end, using Chrome. Lol, this is exactly why I never post on SO, people are way to hostile at the first sign of a mistake. Save your breath on any responses, I won't be coming back to the page :)